# CSS Position fixed limit to inside a div

Tags: html, css

I have a small toolbar div that is position:fixed so it moves as the user scrolls. The toolbar is inside a larger div, however I need the toolbar to **not** scroll out of the parent div - is there any way to do this?

If you don't understand what I mean, take a look: http://flowmainserver.appspot.com/post
(I want the love heart and other button not to scroll out of the large image div because they obstruct the comment box)

Is there any way to achieve this with css or will I need javascript?
Thanks!

Comment: You'll definitely need Javascript

Answer (score 6, accepted):

First, some other pointers:

1. Use a `<!DOCTYPE>` declaration. (using different `<!DOCTYPE>` declarations may require you to make some changes, including addnig `cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0"` to `<table>` tags)
2. **Don't** use a `<center>` element - instead use a combination of `margin:auto` and `text-align:center;`.
3. **Don't** put block level element `<div>` inside an inline level element `<a>` like this: `<a href="/"><div class="title"></div></a>`. Instead, give your `<a>` a `display:block;` CSS property.
4. ... and when you use an [image for text](http://flowmainserver.appspot.com/imgs/logo_med.png) also include that text in the HTML source, but use a CSS `text-indent:-10000px;` to remove it.
5. **Don't** mix XHTML syntax and HTML syntax! You sometimes close empty tags - `<link />` - and sometimes don't `<img>`. Choose one or the other, and use the appropriate `<!DOCTYPE>`
6. Once you've done all this, you might as well toss in `alt` attributes on `<img />` tags and `rows` and `cols` on `<textarea>` tags to validate your HTML document.

This will result in much more consistent behavior between browsers and better accessibility. Toss in some `<h1>`...`<h6>` headers are you're pretty solid on the SEO too.

### Cut to the Point

As for your question... perhaps if you just made it go *behind* the comments?

Put this in a `.html` file:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xml:lang="en" lang="en">
<head>
        <base href="http://flowmainserver.appspot.com/" /> <!-- remove this when you put it online -->
    <!-- Copyright Cal Smith 2010 $(window).height()-->
    <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4.2/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="js/jquery.scrollTo-min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">$(window)._scrollable();</script>
    <link href="buttons.css" media="all" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
    <link href="main.css" media="all" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" id="main_css" />

    <title>flow | post title</title>
    <script type="text/javascript">/*
    $(window).scroll(function(){
        if($(window).scrollTop() == $(document).height() - $(window).height()){
            document.location = "http://www.google.com";
        }
    });
    */</script>
    <style type="text/css">
        html body {
            text-align:center;
        }
        html body div.pageHolder {
            margin:auto;
        }
        html body a.title {
            text-indent:-10000px;
            display:block;
        }
        html body table {
            position:relative;
            z-index:10;
            background:url(imgs/dark_bg.png) repeat;
        }
        html body table table td {
            padding-bottom:5px;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="pageHolder" style="margin:auto;">
        <a href="/" class="title">Flow</a>
        <div class="directory">
            <p class="categoryTitle">Post title<span class="categoryTitleBy">&nbsp;2 weeks ago by @<a href="#" class="categoryTitleByA">author url</a></span></p>
            <div class="postDescription"></div>
            <div class="heartOff" title="Click to heart">&hearts;</div>
            <div class="commentTab" onclick="$(window).scrollTo( $('#commentBoxTitle'), 380 ); $('#commentBox').focus();" title="Comments">&Xi;&nbsp;</div>
            <div class="postFull" style="background-image: url(example_full.png); height: 500px; width: 1300px;"></div>
            <table border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
                <tr>
                    <td valign="top">
                        <span class="commentBoxTitle" id="commentBoxTitle">Comment</span>
                        <textarea id="commentBox" class="commentBox"></textarea>
                        <div align="right"><div class="commentPostButton">Post</div></div>
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <div class="commentsHolder">
                            <table border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
                                <tr>
                                    <td valign="top"><img src="http://s3.amazonaws.com/forrst-production/users/photos/10587/xl.png?1280926926" class="commentUserPic" /></td>
                                    <td><div class="commentBody">Vivamus id mollis quam. Morbi ac commodo nulla. In condimentum orci id nisl volutpat bibendum. Quisque commodo hendrerit lorem quis egestas. Maecenas quis tortor arcu. Vivamus rutrum nunc non neque consectetur quis placerat neque lobortis. Nam vestibulum, arcu sodales feugiat consectetur, nisl orci bibendum elit, eu euismod magna sapien ut nibh. Donec semper quam scelerisque tortor dictum gravida. In hac habitasse platea dictumst. Nam pulvinar, odio sed rhoncus suscipit, sem diam ultrices mauris, eu consequat purus metus eu velit. Proin metus odio, aliquam eget molestie nec, gravida ut sapien.</div></td>
                                </tr>
                                <tr>
                                <td valign="top"><img src="http://s3.amazonaws.com/forrst-production/users/photos/7825/xl.png?1278955396" class="commentUserPic" /></td>
                                    <td><div class="commentBody">Quisque eget odio ac lectus vestibulum faucibus eget in metus. In pellentesque faucibus. Quisque eget odio ac lectus vestibulum faucibus eget in metus. In pellentesque faucibus.</div></td>
                                </tr>
                                <tr>
                                    <td valign="top"><img src="http://s3.amazonaws.com/forrst-production/users/photos/10587/xl.png?1280926926" class="commentUserPic" /></td>
                                    <td><div class="commentBody">Vivamus id mollis quam. Morbi ac commodo nulla. In condimentum orci id nisl volutpat bibendum. Quisque commodo hendrerit lorem quis egestas. Maecenas quis tortor arcu. Vivamus rutrum nunc non neque consectetur quis placerat neque lobortis. Nam vestibulum, arcu sodales feugiat consectetur, nisl orci bibendum elit, eu euismod magna sapien ut nibh. Donec semper quam scelerisque tortor dictum gravida. In hac habitasse platea dictumst. Nam pulvinar, odio sed rhoncus suscipit, sem diam ultrices mauris, eu consequat purus metus eu velit. Proin metus odio, aliquam eget molestie nec, gravida ut sapien.</div></td>
                                </tr>
                                <tr>
                                    <td valign="top"><img src="http://s3.amazonaws.com/forrst-production/users/photos/7825/xl.png?1278955396" class="commentUserPic" /></td>
                                    <td><div class="commentBody">Quisque eget odio ac lectus vestibulum faucibus eget in metus. In pellentesque faucibus. Quisque eget odio ac lectus vestibulum faucibus eget in metus. In pellentesque faucibus.</div></td>
                                </tr>
                            </table>
                        </div>
                    </td>
                </tr>
            </table>
            <div class="footer">created by cal smith</div>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: @Cal S - Why thank you! I think you should also consider looking into a JS solution, but at least this way it will degrade gracefully.

Answer (score 1):

Please put a `<div style="clear:both"></div>` right after the small toolbar div. It should float inside the parent div.

Hope that helps,

Comment: Hmm didn't seem to work. Where do you mean by right after the small toolbar?

Comment: `<div class="commentTab" onclick="$(window).scrollTo( $('#commentBoxTitle'), 380 ); $('#commentBox').focus();" title="Comments">Ξ&nbsp;</div><div style="clear:both"></div` 

Like that.

Comment: Still didn't seem to work, I've updated it if you want to see for yourself http://flowmainserver.appspot.com/post

Comment: I'm cuban. Not allowed to enter that site. I mean after the </div> closing tag of the small toolbar div.

Comment: If the parent div should not move too, why don't you use the same position:fixed on the parent div?